# All REST APIs are not loaded if the REST controller class and interface have an API annotated with @HystrixCommand

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix

I have started using spring boot 1.4.1 and spring cloud Camden.RELEASE.

I have created two simple REST controller classes along with their interfaces. I have placed @HystrixCommand annotation on one API of the first controller class and interface both. I have also added fallback method in the same controller class and interface. Code compilation goes fine, and service loads fine too. But I see the first REST controller class REST APIs are not loaded/mapped, meaning calling those REST APIs returns 404. I had a 2nd REST controller without any @HystrixCommand, and API belonging to this class loads fine.

If I simply comment out 'implements < interface name >' in the first REST controller class, everything starts working.

What is the remedy?

Some dummy code snippet to help understand the issue -

```
public interface FirstRESTController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/aa", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   ResponseEntity<String> getAA();

   @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "reliable")
   @RequestMapping(value = "/bb", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   ResponseEntity<String> getBB();

   public ResponseEntity<String> reliable();
}

@RestController
class FirstRESTControllerImpl implements FirstRESTController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/aa", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    ResponseEntity<String> getAA() { ... }

    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "reliable")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/bb", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    ResponseEntity<String> getBB() { ... }

    public ResponseEntity<String> reliable() { ... }
}

---------------------------------------------------------------------
public interface SecondRESTController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/cc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    ResponseEntity<String> getCC();
}

@RestController
class SecondRESTControllerImpl implements SecondRESTController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/cc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    ResponseEntity<String> getCC() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Why do you annotate the methods in the interfaces? Don't forget to annotate the classes with `@RestController`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. Having `@HystrixCommand` on controllers with a fallback doesn't work. Move work to another bean with the hystrix annotation.